# Manually change order of stacked bar charts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart, geom-col

I want to manually change the order of stacked bar charts in order to make my labels readable that have so few observations that they are ontop of each other.
My goal is to set the order to "unclassified", "Fungi", "Viridiplantae" to set the bars with little observations apart from each other.

[I tried the proposed solution here but it would not work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025828/change-the-order-of-stacked-fill-columns-in-ggplot2) Maybe I am missing something?

```
levels(as.factor(totaltibble$kingdom))
[1] "Fungi"         "unclassified"  "Viridiplantae"

phytibble <- psmelt(physeq_comp)
totaltibble <-phytibble %>%
  group_by(Sample, superkingdom, kingdom)%>%
  summarize(sum(Abundance))

        ggplot(totaltibble, aes(superkingdom, `sum(Abundance)`, fill=factor(kingdom, levels=c("unclassified", "Fungi", "Viridiplantae"))))+
      geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom))+
      scale_y_continuous("Anzahl der Reads", labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))+
      scale_fill_manual("Reich", labels = c("Fungi", "unklassifiziert", "Viridiplantae"), values = wes_palette("Darjeeling1") )+
      scale_x_discrete("Domäne", labels = c("Backteria", "Eukaryota", "unklassifiziert", "Viren"))+
      ggtitle("Absolute Häufigkeit nach Reich und Domäne")+
       facet_grid(~Sample, labeller=(Sample=sample_labeller))+
      geom_text(aes(label=`sum(Abundance)`), vjust=1.6)+
      theme_bw()
```

[the Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao4au.png)

The object I am creating the plot from:

```
structure(list(Sample = c("MB5_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_nano", 
"MB6_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_ill", 
"MB6_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_ill", 
"MB5_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_nano", 
"MB6_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_nano", 
"MB5_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_ill", 
"MB6_2020_ill"), superkingdom = c("Eukaryota", "unclassified", 
"Eukaryota", "unclassified", "unclassified", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", 
"unclassified", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", 
"Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Bacteria", 
"Viruses", "Viruses", "Bacteria", "Eukaryota", "Eukaryota", "Viruses", 
"Viruses"), totalreads = c(740180, 740180, 220406, 220406, 122691, 
122691, 41791, 41791, 740180, 220406, 122691, 740180, 740180, 
41791, 220406, 220406, 41791, 740180, 220406, 122691, 41791, 
122691, 122691, 41791), kingdom = c("Fungi", "unclassified", 
"Fungi", "unclassified", "unclassified", "Fungi", "Fungi", "unclassified", 
"unclassified", "unclassified", "unclassified", "unclassified", 
"Viridiplantae", "unclassified", "unclassified", "Viridiplantae", 
"unclassified", "unclassified", "unclassified", "unclassified", 
"Viridiplantae", "Viridiplantae", "unclassified", "unclassified"
), abundance = c(440891, 295055, 126035, 93059, 61774, 60325, 
28618, 12905, 3548, 1021, 591, 437, 224, 220, 191, 93, 47, 25, 
7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), percent = c(59.5653759896241, 39.8626009889486, 
57.1831075379073, 42.2216273604167, 50.3492513713312, 49.1682356489066, 
68.4788590844919, 30.8798545141298, 0.479342862546948, 0.463236028057312, 
0.481697924053109, 0.0590396930476371, 0.0302629090221298, 0.526429135459788, 
0.0866582579421613, 0.0421948585791675, 0.112464406211864, 0.00337755681050555, 
0.0031759570973567, 0.000815055709057714, 0.0023928597066354, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(Sample = c("MB5_2020_ill", 
"MB5_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_ill", "MB5_2020_nano", 
"MB5_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB5_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_ill", 
"MB6_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_ill", "MB6_2020_nano", 
"MB6_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_nano", "MB6_2020_nano"), superkingdom = c("Bacteria", 
"Eukaryota", "unclassified", "Viruses", "Bacteria", "Eukaryota", 
"unclassified", "Viruses", "Bacteria", "Eukaryota", "unclassified", 
"Viruses", "Bacteria", "Eukaryota", "unclassified", "Viruses"
), totalreads = c(122691, 122691, 122691, 122691, 740180, 740180, 
740180, 740180, 41791, 41791, 41791, 41791, 220406, 220406, 220406, 
220406), .rows = structure(list(20L, c(6L, 11L, 22L), 5L, 23L, 
    9L, c(1L, 12L, 13L), 2L, 18L, 17L, c(7L, 14L, 21L), 8L, 24L, 
    10L, c(3L, 15L, 16L), 4L, 19L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the order of stacked fill columns in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025828/change-the-order-of-stacked-fill-columns-in-ggplot2)

Comment: what exactly is not working? Stupid suggestion, have you tried `ungroup` before passing to ggplot? Sometimes grouped data can cause problems (although I don't really think this is the issue here)

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you have two separate places where you map `fill` to `kingdom`:

1. In the top call within `ggplot(... aes(fill=factor(kingdom...`
2. In the call to the geom: `geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom))`

The heirarchy of deciding mapping in `ggplot` uses the mapping in the geom call before the general mapping.  What's happening here is that `geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom))` is overwriting what you're stating in the top call.  It will map the non-refactored `kingdom` column instead of your refactored one.

Easy fix is to use `geom_col()` in place of `geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom))`.

Alternative fixes if you would prefer:

- Change `kingdom` before plotting: `totaltibble$kingdom <- factor(totaltibble$kingdom, levels=c("unclassified", "Fungi", "Viridiplantae"))`
- Duplicate the `aes(fill=...` statement used in `ggplot()` to use in the `geom_col()` statment.
- Remove the `fill=` statemnt in `ggplot()` and move it to `geom_col()`.

In the top-line `ggplot()` you reference and change it, but you are also stating it in the second line: `geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom))`.  Since you *restate* it in `geom_col()`, `ggplot` will use the one stated in the geom call over the general mapping statement.  Just remove it in `geom_col()` - it's not needed there and is causing issues.  So, just `geom_col()` without the `aes()`.  Alternatively, change `kingdom` before you plot or use the same `factor(...` code inside `aes()` for `geom_col()`.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I still don't know what is wrong. I tried all of you suggested solutions and unfortunately none fixed it. The bar segments still are in the same order

Comment: @mr.raccoon, can you share your data or a part of your data so that this becomes reproducible?  Also, I would recommend sharing an image of your plot in your question, because maybe there's something to understand by looking at your output.  To share the data, please share via `dput(totaltibble)` in your console, then copy and paste that output into the question formatted as code.  If it's too large, you can either do something like `dput(head(totaltibble, 25))` or `dput(totaltibble[sample(1:nrow(totaltibble), 25),])`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it again. I changed my original post to include a picture of the ploit and the object I am creating it from via `dput`